# Bash: pinging servers and writing the IP to a file

Tags: linux, bash, ping, host, dig

I currently have to find the IP-Adresses of a lot of servers.

I have written a bash script on linux that creates all the server names.

When I write it like this, I get all servernames, even if there no longer have an IP.

```
host $f$n$d >> IPs.txt
```

Is there a way to only write the servers into the file, that still have an IP, together with the servername.

Kind regards Elias

Comment: what are `$f` `$n` and `$d`?

Comment: You probably can work-up something with `dig`, see https://serverfault.com/q/372066/154366

Comment: ```$f$n$d``` is the declaration of the IP-adress I have to ping.

Comment: OK, so your problem would be: You have a bunch of IP-addresses and you want to check if they still have an associated `PTR Record` in the DNS server?

Comment: Yes, that summs it up...

Answer (score 0):

I think the local DNS resolver caches the IP addresses, so you will get the corresponding IPs even in the scenario you described.

I suggest you to start the script with a full local DNS flush, depending on your distribution and DNS client: [Here are](https://devconnected.com/how-to-flush-dns-cache-on-linux/) son techinques to flush it.

Comment: This will sadly not work, because those IPs where created as "support-IPs" for servers, and when these servers where removed those IPs where left over.  I also have to operate from a server with this script, on which I am probably not allowed to do such things...

Comment: I understand. I suggest you to post this questo on **UnixStackExchange** for a better support.